# _framework/blazor.web.js fails to load with 404 when changing the base URL of a .NET 8 Blazor Web App

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

I have .NET 8 Blazor Web App that I've created from the Visual Studio template. It has server and client projects.
I need to change the base URL of the application to be `/portals/sales`. Here are the changes that I've made

1. Inside `Program.cs`

   ```cs
   app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles(new PathString("/portals/sales"));
   app.UseStaticFiles("/portals/sales");
   app.UseAntiforgery();

   app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
       .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
       .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode(options =>
           options.PathPrefix = "/portals/sales")
       .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(MK.Sales.Portal.Client._Imports).Assembly);
   ```
2. Inside the `App.razor`

   ```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">

   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
       <base href="/portals/sales/" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="MK.Sales.Portal.styles.css" />
       <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
       <HeadOutlet />
   </head>

   <body>
       <Routes />
       <script src="/portals/sales/_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
   </body>

   </html>
   ```
3. Inside the server `csproj`

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
     <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
     <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
     <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
     <StaticWebAssetBasePath>/portals/sales/</StaticWebAssetBasePath>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```

When I launch the application under `https://localhost:5001/portals/sales` URL, everything loads correctly, except the `_framework/blazor.web.js`. I receive 404 and the `_framework/blazor.web.js` is not loaded.

When I manually load `https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.web.js`, it loads just fine.

I am not sure what am I missing, but Blazor fails to supply the `_framework/blazor.web.js` from the overridden base path `/portals/sales`. Instead, the `_framework/blazor.web.js` remains at the base path.

What should I change in my code to make Blazor supply the `_framework/blazor.web.js` from the `/portals/sales` base path?

## Update 1

I've uploaded the sample project into my GitHub account and you can find it [here](https://github.com/kyurkchyan/BlazorCustomBaseUrl)

## Update 2

It seems this is a bug. I've opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/54525)

Comment: The URLs are relative to `base`. You already specified `base href="/portals/sales/"` so your code is actually looking at `/portals/sales/portals/sales/_framework/blazor.web.js`

Comment: You can check what's going on in the Network tab of the browser's Developer Tools. This way you can see which URL was actually used

Comment: I did check the network tab. It tries to load the blazor.web.js from GET https://localhost:5001/portals/sales/_framework/blazor.web.js

So, the path is set correctly. The problem is that for some reason the blazor.web.js is located at GET https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.web.js instead

Comment: I've run into this in the past too, when I wanted to create and test a Blazor hosted app that would run at a specific IIS virtual folder. If you deploy on IIS, things work just by changing the `base`. Kestrel though listens to the root only. You have to tell it to start on a different "folder' with `--pathbase=/portals/salses`. You can specify this in `launchsettings.json` by adding `"commandLineArgs": "--pathbase=/portals/sales",` to the  server's profile. I didn't modify any paths in code, except for `base`

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help @PanagiotisKanavos. I've uploaded the sample project to my github.

https://github.com/kyurkchyan/BlazorCustomBaseUrl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way of configuring custom base URL in Blazor is using `UsePathBase`

Here's the success path of having a custom base URL

1. In the default Blazor template add `UsePathBase` right after the `build.Build`

   ```
   var app = builder.Build();

   app.UsePathBase("/portals/sales");
   ```
2. Modify the `App.razor` similar to this

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">

   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8"/>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
       <base href="/portals/sales/"/>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"/>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css"/>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="BlazorCustomBaseUrl.styles.css"/>
       <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
       <HeadOutlet/>
   </head>

   <body>
   <Routes/>
   <script src="/portals/sales/_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
   </body>

   </html>
   ```
3. Update the page URLs of your pages. For instance my `Weather.razor` has this `@page "/portals/sales/weather"`
4. Update the `NavMenu.razor` urls to have the `/portal/sales` as a base path. For instance, the weather URL has this

```
<NavLink class="nav-link" href="/portals/sales/weather">...
```

5. Add this to your server project properties inside the `csproj`

   ```
   <StaticWebAssetBasePath>/portals/sales</StaticWebAssetBasePath>
   ```

After doing all of the above steps, I was successfully been able to launch and deploy our blazor app with a custom base path.

The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/kyurkchyan/BlazorCustomBaseUrl)

Answer (score 0):

you already set base url as

```
<base href="/portals/sales/" />
```

remove `/portals/sales/` from the `blazor.web.js` as it is appending as `/portals/sales/portals/sales/`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but It tries to load the blazor.web.js from GET localhost:5001/portals/sales/_framework/blazor.web.js So, the path is set correctly. The problem is that for some reason the blazor.web.js is located at localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.web.js instead